# How to plot the field of view of an Earth-Observation satellite when close to the poles using basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy, satellite, fieldofview

I am trying to draw the maximum (theoretical) field of view of a satellite along its orbit. I am using Basemap, on which I want to plot different positions along the orbit (with scatter), and I would like to add the whole field of view using the tissot method (or equivalent).
The code below works fine until the latitude reaches about 75 degrees North, on a 300km altitude orbit. Beyond which the code outputs a ValueError:
"ValueError: undefined inverse geodesic (may be an antipodal point)"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import math

earth_radius = 6371000.  # m
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), edgecolor='w')
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l',
            llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90,
            llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180)

# draw the coastlines on the empty map
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')

# define the position of the satellite
position = [300000., 75., 0.]  # altitude, latitude, longitude

# radius needed by the tissot method
radius = math.degrees(math.acos(earth_radius / (earth_radius + position[0])))
m.tissot(position[2], position[1], radius, 100, facecolor='tab:blue', alpha=0.3)
m.scatter(position[2], position[1], marker='*', c='tab:red')

plt.show()
```

To be noted that the code works fine at the south pole (latitude lower than -75). I know it's a known bug, is there a known workaround for this issue?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you found is some of Basemap's limitations. Let's switch to Cartopy for now. The working code will be different but not much.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import math

earth_radius = 6371000.
position = [300000., 75., 0.]   # altitude (m), lat, long
radius = math.degrees(math.acos(earth_radius / (earth_radius + position[0])))
print(radius)  # in subtended degrees??

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

img_extent = [-180, 180, -90, 90]

# here, cartopy's' `PlateCarree` is equivalent with Basemap's `cyl` you use
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.PlateCarree(), extent = img_extent)

# for demo purposes, ...
# let's take 1 subtended degree = 112 km on earth surface (*** you set the value as needed ***)
ax.tissot(rad_km=radius*112, lons=position[2], lats=position[1], n_samples=64, \
             facecolor='red', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.15, alpha = 0.3)

ax.coastlines(linewidth=0.15)
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False, linewidth=1, color='blue', alpha=0.3, linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

With the code above, the resulting plot is:

[image]

Now, if we use Orthographic projection, (replace relevant line of code with this)

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude=0.0, central_latitude=60.0))
```

you get this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I believe this is what I want. I'll give Cartopy a try. Cheers

Comment: I am a little late to this discussion, but the variable radius is the angle, so alpha = math.acos(earth_radius / (earth_radius + position[0])); radius = alpha * earth_radius; so shouldn't the plot be like: ax.tissot(rad_km=radius/1000.....?